# Weird PHP problem

Tags: php

I have the following code...

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('myDB.php');
  if (isset($_POST))
  {
     foreach($GLOBALS['myDB']->getShops()as $i)
     {
       $tempLat = $i['latitude'];
       $templong  = $i['longitude'];
       $distance = distance($_POST['latitude'],$_POST['longitude'],$tempLat,$templong);
       if($distance <= 300)
       {
          echo "".$i['id']."|".$i['shopName']."|".$i['longitude']."|".$i['latitude']."|".$i['advert']."|";
       }      
     }
  }
  function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  return (($miles * 1.609344)*1000);
 }
?>
```

---

Now when I get to see that page it gives me Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) and it says that the website may be temporarily down...If i try to open the page using firefox it opens a dialog for downloading the php file...

What I would like to do is to have it print either the echoes (if distance is in fact bigger than 300 meters) or nothing at all but it should still be an empty html page...

Can anyone see whats wrong with that???

NOTE: The code works fine locally but not on my server..however every other page works as expected so the server is up and running...

Comment: `Error 324` is a Chrome error code, and (probably) doesn't have anything to do with your PHP. Can you post the `headers` that your browsers get when you try to load the page?

Comment: @jnpcl I tried different browsers even different pcs and still the same...in the header it says that the page is not available...

Comment: getting prompted to download the .php file instead of getting its output means something blew up past the point where even PHP's internal handlers could catch it. Check the server's error logs for anything that would look relevant.

Comment: @Marc B Thats what I thought but how come it works locally???

Comment: Because it's a different environment? "Why does not one understand me when I speak English in Tibet? Everyone understands me at home!"

Comment: @Marc B Fair enough i guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after commenting out and uncommenting each line one by one I found where the problem is...

```
 foreach($GLOBALS['myDB']->getShops()as $i)
```

The query in the database was failing because of the type of a field set to longtext...

Makes no sense at all but changing that to varchar fixed the problem...

Comment: this should be in your original question as an update rather than an answer.

Comment: @Serge How bout now?? At first I thought I fixed it and put it as an answer but then it turned out I was wrong...Thats definitely the answer now though...

Answer (score 0):

If i read your code right, you are only going to get a response from that if $distance is > 300.  Something to consider.

Comment: That is correct but the values that Im passing in definitely return a result that is <300

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put an ELSE statement after your IF. You'll see it's just printing an HTML skeleton.

Obviously, you'll want a doctype declaration and maybe a nice message saying "No results", but you get the idea...

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('myDB.php');
  if (isset($_POST))
  {
     foreach($GLOBALS['myDB']->getShops()as $i)
     {
       $tempLat = $i['latitude'];
       $templong  = $i['longitude'];
       $distance = distance($_POST['latitude'],$_POST['longitude'],$tempLat,$templong);
       if($distance <= 300)
       {
          echo "".$i['id']."|".$i['shopName']."|".$i['longitude']."|".$i['latitude']."|".$i['advert']."|";
       }      
     }
  }
else{
  print '<html><Head><title></title></Head><body></body></html>';
}
  function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  return (($miles * 1.609344)*1000);
 }
?>
```

If you're still getting an error, something is wrong in your include (you'll need to post that), or something in your IF is throwing an exception.

Do you have error reporting on? Have you checked your webserver log? Have you tried wrapping the suspect operations in a try/catch?

Comment: @cinqoTimo Thats not true cause even with nothing at all in the php  it still renders as an empty page...at least in my case...thanks for the reply anyway...

Comment: @mixkat: Do you have other PHP pages on the server that work?

Comment: @cinqoTimo Yup just edited the post as well...all work fine and locally even this one works fine but not on the server for some reason...

Comment: @mixkat - I updated my answer. You'll want some distinct output in the else, just in case things aren't going as expected in your IF. My strategy is usually to pull code out until it works - then you'll have your error. Start by making sure your includes are correct - then try printing all your POST variable. One missing variable could be the culprit

Comment: @mixkat - okay, sorry. I didn't see you had it working in your local. Check server log - are you on apache?

Comment: @cinqoTimo Unfortunately its a uni server and we dont have access to the logs..its really annoying cause you cant actually debug the code there if it works it works if it doesnt...well...

Comment: @mixcat - can you pull a phpinfo()? Are you using any PHP extensions in your include?